# CSS table layout with missing cells

Tags: css, html, tablelayout

I have HTML content from an external source to work with. It is tagged with divs and look somewhat like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="author">Author 1</div>
      <div class="title">Title 1</div>
      <div class="publisher">Publisher</div>
      <div class="year">2012</div>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="author">Author 2</div>
      <div class="title">Title 2</div>
      <div class="year">2013</div>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="author">Author 3</div>
      <div class="title">Title 3</div>
      <div class="publisher">Publisher</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, it would like to display it in a table layout with CSS, with alternating colors for each row. Somewhat like this:

```
body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.book {
  display: table-row;
}

.book:nth-child(even) {
  background: #FFF;
}

.book:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #DDD;
}

.author, .title, .publisher, .year {
  display: table-cell;         
}
```

However, the problem with this solution is that, as you can see, some divs are missing in the HTML and yet I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Have each kind of information be aligned vertically. In other words, have the year of each publication in the above example to be displayed in a different column than publisher information.
2. Have the row coloring extend to cover the width of the page for every row.

Is this even possible using only CSS when I have several columns?

Fiddled - http://jsfiddle.net/sRJhs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final answer, this works the best:

```
.book:nth-child(even) {
    background: #FFF;
}

.book:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #DDD;
}

.book {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.book div {
    float: left;
    left: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
}
.author{
    margin-left: -100%;
}
.title{
    margin-left: -75%;
}
.publisher{
    margin-left: -50%;
}
.year {
    margin-left: -25%;
}
```

New fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sRJhs/17/

Comment: Thanks. That solves part of it, but unfortunately doesn't align the data.

Comment: @Magnus Gustavsson - changed my approach, this works the best

Comment: Thanks again! It's starting to look like a solution. It works well enough in the example, but not with real life data that doesn't fit within the width of the column. I can set the cell width to 25% and increase min-height to be enough for any example data, but to be a real working solution the cell should really be able to expand to contain whatever data is in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Rwn2/

You need to set empty values for your cells that don't have a value. (ex. put a blank space `&nbsp;`)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my HTML and I was interested in if I could do it using only CSS, not by changing the HTML. I do realize I can solve it by transforming the data to add the missing cells.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you align the data on load?

 see here http://jsfiddle.net/ryPPs/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var emptyYearDiv = $('<div class="year">n/a</div>');
var emptyAuthorDiv = $('<div class="author">n/a</div>');
var emptyTitleDiv = $('<div class="title">n/a</div>');
 var emptyPublisherDiv = $('<div class="publisher">n/a</div>');
var emptyYearDiv = $('<div class="year">n/a</div>');

$(".book:not(:has(div[class^=year]))").append(emptyYearDiv);
$(".book:not(:has(div[class^=title]))").append(emptyTitleDiv);
$(".book:not(:has(div[class^=publisher]))").append(emptyPublisherDiv);
$(".book:not(:has(div[class^=year]))").append(emptyYearDiv);
```

});