# CSS approach to tabular layout where certain data items (cells) are missing?

Tags: html, css, xslt, html-table, flexbox

This is similar to the problem brought up in [CSS table layout with missing cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893560/css-table-layout-with-missing-cells).

### Background: the data

I have a very-ugly Excel sheet with 72 different data columns (as of now).  For any given row, any of these data items might be empty.  We're stuck with the Excel file as the authoritative data format, due to various workflow and organizational considerations.

It's possible that the number of columns might change in future (either growing or shrinking).

### Background: the process

I'm using XSL to transform this into various other formats, including HTML.  As part of this, it has been decreed that the HTML use a tabular layout, maintaining superficial similarity to the Excel.  We have the option of using CSS / JavaScript to show or hide columns as needed -- 72 columns is unwieldy, and most users are only interested in certain subsets.

### The question:

Do I really need to generate empty `<td>` elements for missing data items?

→ This is possible, but ugly and tedious.

Is there any elegant way of saying "this `<td>` is for Column 12", and have that line up appropriately under the header for Column 12, even if the `<td>` elements for columns 4 and 7 are missing?

→ Ideally, we'd use some dynamically-generated non-numeric (or at least not-positionally-dependent) identifier to tie together each cell with it's appropriate column header, to avoid the need for too much refactoring if the number or order of columns changes.

#### Additional thoughts:

Flexbox is an option.  I've poked around, and the reordering possibilities are quite attractive.  However, I can't figure out how to get the columnar layout to work correctly if there are any missing elements (not just empty, but missing).

As stated above, the number of columns might change.  We also don't know the column widths ahead of time.  I'd **really** like to avoid hard-coding column widths, even as percentages.

Comment: I would suggest generating empty tds (or divs if you intend to use flexbox) for missing data items to avoid layout alterations and for correct markup. Aside from markup or extra code there is no way of saying "this `td` is for column 12".

Comment: @Jake, so flexbox can reorder, but it can't position?

Comment: My google-fu was failing me earlier, but now I think I may have found what I need:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column.asp.  Allows me to specify that a given cell should appear in a given column, regardless of how many elements precede it.  See also https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-row-column/

Comment: Grid would way better in your case indeed. Flexbox can reorder in the same container but cannot be deplaced in other containers, it would depend on your HTML structure basically. [This article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/02/complex-web-tables/) about complex web tables just came out on smashing, I suggest you give it a look